# JNDI configuration for Wso2 EI 7.1.0

Tags: wso2

I need a sample configuration to keep JNDI in Wso2 EI and those name can be reuse in DB report mediator.

Thanks,

Ajay Babu Maguluri.

Comment: Try to elaborate what do you want to achieve, what have you tried and what are you struggling with exactly.

Comment: I need to keep db report mediator in one of our use case flow,  as of now we tried this with connection pool which db report mediator internally had, I want to take that connection from common connection pool with JNDI , so that I can reuse same connection even when other db report added to my flow.

Comment: Datasources are to be defined in the conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml, if you're using the deployment.toml , the master-datasources.xml is tempplated from the toml file, then the datasource needs to be defined in the toml file

Comment: Can you explain what is this toml file and how to create custom jndi inside that.

Answer (score 0):

Find the deployment.toml file, it is a data source from which other config file are templated.

An example configuration creating a jdbc datasource inside the `deployment.toml` with name `jndi/MY_DATA` is like:

```
[[datasource]]
id = "MY_DATA"  # "WSO2_COORDINATION_DB"
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydata"
username = "root"
password = "root"
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

optionally you can specify other jdbc properties just after the `[[datasource]]` section

```
[datasource.pool_options]
maxActive = 10
maxWait = 60000
minIdle = 0
testOnBorrow = true
defaultAutoCommit = true
validationInterval = 30000
testWhileIdle = true
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
removeAbandoned = true
logAbandoned = true
removeAbandonedTimeout = 180
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
```